# Find views against a table that include a WHERE clause in the view definition

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to identify all the views that are conditioned on a status code from a primary table.  Most of these views were created in the past (by other dba's), and I'm wanting to add a new status code and verify whether it will be included or excluded from the various views.

What I think might exist:

```
CREATE VIEW StaffonActiveDuty AS
SELECT Name, [Rank], SerialNumber
FROM Enlisted
WHERE Status = 'Active'
```

Best case results would be to identify all the views over the Enlisted table with a where clause that contains the status column.  Next best would be to identify views over the Enlisted table with a where clause.

I have code that will return all the views that reference the Enlisted table; but this table has hundreds of views using it.  I'm hoping to cut down the number of views where I have to retrieve the source to determine whether my new status code will cause issues or need to be added to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following to find all the views that reference the target table, *Enlisted*, and return any whose definition contains the text string specified:

```
select v.[name], m.definition 
from sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities('dbo.Enlisted', 'object') r
join sys.views v on v.object_id = r.referencing_id
join sys.sql_modules m on m.object_id = r.referencing_id
where m.definition like '%Status%''Active''%';
```

Comment: Stu . . . that was exactly what I needed.  Cut down my list of views to under a dozen.  Thank you so much!